# Chef Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[httpd]'

Tags: ruby, apache, centos, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Here is my very basic recipes/default.rb file;

```
package "httpd" do
        action :install
end

node["apache"]["sites"].each do |sitename, data|
        document_root = "/content/sites/#{sitename}"

        directory document_root do
                mode "0755"
                recursive true
        end

template "/etc/httpd/conf.d/#{sitename}.conf" do
        source "vhost.erb"
        mode "0644"
        variables(
                :document_root => document_root,
                :port => data["port"],
                :domain => data["domain"]
        )
        notifies :restart, "service[httpd]"
end

end

service "httpd" do
        action [:enable, :start]
end
```

When I run the chef-client in the node it returns the following error:

```
Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[httpd]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of /sbin/service httpd start ----
    STDOUT: Starting httpd: [FAILED]
    STDERR: Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/stedelahunty2.conf:
    order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or 'mutual-failure'
    ---- End output of /sbin/service httpd start ----
    Ran /sbin/service httpd start returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache/recipes/default.rb

     35: service "httpd" do
     36:    action [:enable, :start]
     37: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache/recipes/default.rb:35:in `from_file'

    service("httpd") do
      action [:enable, :start]
      supports {:restart=>false, :reload=>false, :status=>true}
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      service_name "httpd"
      enabled true
      pattern "httpd"
      declared_type :service
      cookbook_name "apache"
      recipe_name "default"
    end
```

I've tried renaming it apache, changing the options to ':restart', commenting out entirely but that means httpd fails to start. I just need a simple way to restart the service after the chef run has completed.

Again, apologies for the novice question; I'm very new to coding.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That's not a chef problem. Apache httpd reports

> Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/stedelahunty2.conf: order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or 'mutual-failure'

Comment: Ahh ok, so as it is going to be a basic apache server, which of those options should I leave in?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. What do you want to achieve and how does the `vhost.erb` in the cookbook resp. `/etc/httpd/conf.d/stedelahunty2.conf` on the node look like?

Comment: I copied and pasted from another example into my recipe and it seems to have worked. Unfortunately this hasn't given me the knowledge to fix my solution in the future but it's working for now. Appreciate you trying to help. Thank you

Comment: What I can read from the error message was that the argument supplied to the [Order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) directive was not valid. You can at least read the docs in order to understand, what it is doing. I can't say, if `Order` hat zero or more than one argument in you previously generated template.

Comment: As StephenKing said, this is an apache problem, not a chef problem.  Perhaps post your stedelahunty2.conf file in a new question and tag that question with `apache` and see if the apache folks can help you understand why it was bad.  If you post the .erb file we may be able to help you understand why you got a bad value there.